# Online user for a period in Openfire

Tags: openfire

In Openfire admin console "online user" details are available but I am unable to retrieve active users for a specific duration (like last 7 days or 30 days).
I am able to get the session table (fpsession) in database but the user count is not changing in database when users are connecting or session is closed.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Openfire doesn't provide such service metrices. And fpsession table is used by Fast Path Plugin, which is again out of context.

You might consider using analytics on mobile side for such stats or else you customize Openfire to log data to a table or to a file whenever a user logs in and later-on you can perform analytics on that data. But that are totally custom business requirements.

Comment: In openfire console the statistics about user count is available with custom period. In that case the user details should be available in database/configuration files?

Comment: Those are in-memory stats for particular session and once a user disconnects, this info is removed.

Comment: In Openfire console we have "Archive search" option and it has the details about chat history. As per my understanding it is coming from "ofmessagearchive" table in database.
Please suggest if this is the right table to check for active user details for a period.

Comment: ofConversation, ofMessageArchive tables belong to Monitoring Plugin and if you are using it then yes you can extract some metrices on your own using the data of ofMessageArchive. Like Max no. of chat messages sent in a minute, hour, day etc. Active users in an hour, day etc